# How to minus the count of a product where particular condition is true

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
    Date     Visitorid  Visitnumber  Condition A 
    1/1/2017    123        2             OF
    1/1/2017    123        3             OF
    1/1/2017    123        30            ABC
    1/2/2017    123        34            OP
    1/1/2017    124        1             OF
    1/2/2017    124        2             OP
```

I want to [minus](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) the visit number where `visitorId` has visited 'OF' first then visited 'OP' (but it should be on different dates) and also want to group the above result as

```
 Count of visitor_ids where minus (of visit number is 1)
 Count of visitor_ids where minus (of visit number is 2)
```

and so on

Comment: With that sample data, what's the expected result? (Formatted text here, too.)

Comment: Expected result is 
1 - 1 ( how many visitors have visited OF then OP after one visitnumber)
1 - 32( how many visitors have visited OF then OP after 32 visitnumber)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Snowflake.

Comment: Can you please try to explain it in more detail? Your explanation is hard to graps. Maybe you can also describe exactly the output in a tabular format, and exactly you got to these numbers